# Analysis of the most common words in a text

Tags: c#, natural-language-processing

I have been trying to gain more understanding and experience in the `NPL` area and to get some more practice. I decided to attempt to create a simple high-level analysis program.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Add a function that allows me to read in a full document (wordpad) instead of Console.Readline(); with CMD input
- Improve organization, cleaner, or shorter code
- Count words

The Code:

```
namespace HOMEWORK
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) //2 foreach() 2 for() 4 if() 28 .methods//
        {
            LinkedList<MatchCounter> matchCounters = new LinkedList<MatchCounter>();
            string[] currentPats = new[] { "the", "in" };
            StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < currentPats.Length; i++)
            {
                SB.Append(@"(?=(?<p").Append(i).Append(">").Append(currentPats[i]).Append("))?");
            }

            Regex regexx = new Regex(SB.ToString(), RegexOptions.Compiled);
            Console.WriteLine("CURRENT PATTERN: {0}", regexx);

            string input = Console.ReadLine(); 
            Console.WriteLine("input: {0} ", input);

            foreach (Match match in regexx.Matches(input).Cast<Match>())  
            {
                ;
                for (var i = 0; i < currentPats.Length; i++)
                {
                    Group group = match.Groups["p" + i]; 

                    if (!group.Success)
                        continue;

                    if (group.Value != "") 
                    {
                        bool isFound = false;

                        foreach (MatchCounter copy in matchCounters)
                        {
                            if (copy.GetSyllable() == group.Value)
                            {
                                copy.Increment();
                                isFound = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!isFound)
                            matchCounters.AddLast(new MatchCounter(group.Value));
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Matched pattern #{0}: '{1}' at index {2}", i, group.Value, group.Index);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class MatchCounter
    {
        int count;
        string syllable;

        public MatchCounter(string Syl)
        {
            count = 1;
            syllable = Syl;
        }

        public string GetSyllable()
        {
            return syllable;
        }

        public void Increment()
        {
            count++;
        }

        public int GetCount()
        {
            return count;
        }    
    }
}
```

I am still a learner and would like my code to be reviewed with feedback. I would greatly appreciate any feedback about the code quality, performance or any other possible corrections or how to do things differently.

Comment: I downvoted your question because you did not explain how the algorithm works and what you are doing exactly and how. You also did not provide any examples.

Comment: You should know that in most regex flavours look arounds are not quantifiable. The .Net implementation is one of the only ones I know of that allows for an optional lookahead. There's also no point in it. Just make your group optional. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Please edit where you say NPL to NLP, I would but I can't change that few characters a.k.a. 2